# Child observable in a ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-jqautocomplete

I have some trouble with some child properties of a ko viewmodel. The child properties are not observable with autocomplete and therefore the UI / view is not updated after adding some new (in this example) phonenumbers. For the autocomplete functionality i use the knockout-jqAutocomplete of rniemeyer.

**View**

```
    <input data-bind="jqAuto: { source: searchCustomer, value: selectedCustomer, inputProp: 'Name', labelProp: 'Name', options: { delay: 250 } }" id="Customer_Name" name="Customer.Name" type="text" value="">

<div class="phone-list" data-bind="visible: selectedCustomer().PhoneNumbers.length > 0, foreach: selectedCustomer().PhoneNumbers">
    <input type="hidden" data-bind='attr: { name: "Customer.PhoneNumbers["+$index()+"].Id", value: Id}' />
    <input type="text" data-bind='attr: { name: "Customer.PhoneNumbers["+$index()+"].Number", value: Number}' />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    function ViewModel(addressUrl) {
    var $self = this;

    $self.selectedCustomer = ko.observable(),

    $self.searchCustomer = function (searchTerm, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/customers/search/?query=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm),
                cache: true,
                dataType: "json"
        }).done(callback);
    }

            $self.addPhoneNumber = function () {
                $self.selectedCustomer().PhoneNumbers.push({ Id: 0, Number: '' });
            }

            $self.removePhoneNumber = function (phoneNumber) {
                $self.selectedCustomer().PhoneNumbers.remove(phoneNumber);
            }
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**JSON data (Result)**

```
{  
   "Id":1,
   "Name":"Test customer",
   "PhoneNumbers":[  
      {  
         "Number":"123456789",
         "CreatedOnUtc":"/Date(1474299252213)/",
         "Id":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Thanks.

Kind regards,

Flaminio

**UPDATE**

I have created a
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1o60m13/3/) for this matter, anyone can solves this?

Comment: You can use ko.mapping plugin (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to make object structure observable.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand you correctly because it make no sense to but a ko.mapping result in a ko.observable or do i miss something?

Comment: This makes child properties observable, thus model changes will be reflected in the UI immediately.

Comment: I have made a fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/o1o60m13/3/), can you look at it?

Comment: I'll try. It's rather massive...

Comment: I'm sorry, your sample is too large.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

If the only observable you have is `selectedCustomer`, maybe the easiest thing to do is to call

```
$self.selectedCustomer.valueHasMutated();
```

whenever you make a change to `PhoneNumbers`.